# Patch an executable file

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, exe, patch

**In short**

What would be the easiest way to make sure that the high word of `ecx` contains 0 by replacing following instruction in the exe file?

```
004044be 0fbf4dfc        movsx   ecx,word ptr [ebp-4]
```

Instead of containing `FFFF9298` after executing adress `004044be` I'd like `ecx` to contain `00009298`.

**What have I tried**

I have tried replacing `movsx` with a simple `mov`by replacing the opcode `0fbf` in the executable with `8b0c` but that didn't work out as planned *(using the debugger to verify the change, I'm sure it was at the the right place)*

**Some background**

I have a rather old program that for one reason or another AV's when I try to print to my HP printer. Everything works fine when I print to CutePDF so the current workaround is to generate a PDF file and print the PDF.

Getting my feet wet with WinDbg I tried to find the reason of why this was happening. 
While this is not the root cause of my problem, it seems that `ecx` at some point get's a negative value which is used to allocate memory, ultimately resulting in an exception.

I could try to find *why* a negative value is returned but during my debugging session, I noticed that zeroing out the high word in `ecx` did the job *(aka printed the file)*.

So instead of containing `FFFF9298` after executing adress `004044be` I'd like `ecx` to contain `00009298`.

```
004044ac 0fbf05e8025100  movsx   eax,word ptr [Encore32!SystemsPerPageDlogProc+0x10e4a1 (005102e8)]
004044b3 05416f0000      add     eax,6F41h
004044b8 668945fc        mov     word ptr [ebp-4],ax
004044bc 6a40            push    40h
004044be 0fbf4dfc        movsx   ecx,word ptr [ebp-4] --> replace with ?
004044c2 51              push    ecx
004044c3 8b55f8          mov     edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]
004044c6 52              push    edx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `movzx`, it does exactly what you need.

[The opcode](http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/MOVZX) (for 16->32 version) is `0F B7 /r` so just patching BF to B7 should do it.

Answer (score 3):

[`movsx`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/movsx.html) mean "move with sign extend". That means that the top bit of src is copied to all high bits of dest. You don't want that.

[`movzx`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/movzx.html) fills top bits with 0.

`movzx ecx,word ptr [ebp-4]` is what you need. Using 32-bit code as in your example it can be encoded as `0F B7 4D FC`.

Comment: +1 - I really would love to accept both answers. Yours is more detailed, but Igor's was first. thx and hat off to both of you.